Nodemon Crashes with 'bad ELF magic' Error on Termux in Android
I'm using Termux on my Android phone to run a simple Node.js server with nodemon. My server script (index.js) is written in JavaScript and should work fine, but when I run it with nodemon, I get the error:
error: "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/backend/index.js" has bad ELF magic: 636f6e73
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I've verified that the index.js file contains valid JavaScript code. Running the script directly with node works fine, but nodemon fails with the above error. I've tried recreating the file and reinstalling nodemon, but the issue persists. How can I fix this?
What I Tried:
I installed Node.js and nodemon in Termux and created a basic Express.js server script (index.js). When running the script with nodemon using:

nodemon ~/backend/index.js


What I Expected:
I expected nodemon to start the server and monitor the file for changes, allowing the server to restart automatically when changes are made.
What Actually Happened:
Instead, I received the error:

error: "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/backend/index.js" has bad ELF magic: 636f6e73

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


This indicates that nodemon is failing to start the server and is treating the index.js file as a binary rather than a JavaScript file.
